# Creating a new sw<xxx>dp qualifier

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I have the qualifiers for 7 inch tablets and 10 inch tablets, sw600dp and sw720dp respectively. I don't understand how those numbers were reached.

I would like to create a new layout for phones which a smaller screen size than 4 inches. Please could you explain how I should do this using the smallest width qualifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please checkout ["Configuration example"](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) section of official documentation first. It explains very well what is used and when. In your case *default layout folder* without a qualifier is used for handsets.

What is smallest width qualifier? Smallest width is

> The fundamental size of a screen, as indicated by the shortest
>   dimension of the available screen area. Specifically, the device's
>   smallestWidth is the shortest of the screen's available height and
>   width (you may also think of it as the "smallest possible width" for
>   the screen).

For instance your have a phone with screen size equals to 480x800 dp. The smallest width for this device will be the smallest value of these two, which is 480dp. If you rotate your device, the smallest value will stay unchanged - 480dp.

How to use smallest width qualifier? When you create a layout you always expect a minimum width, with witch it swill looks good. Below this minimum your layout gets squeezed and doesn't look good. To make sure this doesn't happen to it, you put it to the folder with `sw<N>dp` qualifier, when N the minimal allowed width.

It's worth to mention that because smallest width doesn't depend on orientation, you should take case for handling landscape and portrait orientation by yourself by using `land` or `port` qualifiers. Although this approach works, it can become complicated to handle different widths and orientations very soon. To address this issue, there is another approach called *responsive mobile design*. I suggest to read a series of articles ["Deep dive into responsive mobile design"](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2011/11/08/deep-dive-into-responsive-mobile-design-part-1.html) to get better understanding.

**Update:**

The formula for calculating dp from px is like following:

> dp = px / (ppi / 160dp)

Nexus 7 takes sw-600dp, because all calculations are based on `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density` value coded in the device. This is not the real value, but a rounded value. For Nexus 7 (2013) the real value is 323/160 = 2.01875. The value coded in the device is 2, which corresponds sw-600dp. This is where some pixels get lost.

Comment: Thanks, that is very useful.  But I still don't understand how to calculate the width of a device in density pixels.  Say I have a Nexus 4.  The screen is 1280x768 pixels, the pixel density is 318ppi, and the screen size is 4.7 inches. What would the width be?

Comment: I think I worked it out.  Is it: dp = `px/(ppi/160)`.  However, why does this give the Nexus 7 2013 a smallest dp width of 594, but it uses resources from sw-600dp?

Comment: The formula is correct. Nexus 7 takes sw-600dp because all calculations are based on `displayMetrics.density` value coded in the device. This is not the real value, but rounded value. For Nexus 7 (2013) the real value is 323ppi/160dip=2.01875. The value coded in the device is 2, which corresponds sw-600dp. This is where the pixels get lost. I will update he answer too.

Comment: Hmm, how about a device like Samsung S3 Mini, with 4", 480 x 800 px, and ~233 ppi. Now, 233/160 is 1.456; how do I know if `displayMetrics.density` for that device is 1 or 2? (Or can it also be rounded to 1.5?)

Comment: @Jonik Most likely it will be rounded to 1.5, but you don't need to know this for designing your UI. You just test your layouts for all switching points in dips and you can be sure Android will display them properly on every device. Switching point is the size in dips when app switches from one layout to another. For instance, you have same layout in layout and layout/sw-600dp. 600 dp is the switching point.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, what I didn't realise was that density isn't always rounded to an integer. Actually the background for that was wondering [which devices my `requiresSmallestWidthDp` config will match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079143/how-to-preview-which-devices-a-requiressmallestwidthdp-config-matches). (I do know what minimum dp width my app currently supports, and can already use the layout size qualifiers pretty fluently.)

Answer (score -2):

sw600dp means **smallest screen width** of density 600dp. But let me tell you that you need more than this because Nexus 7 (2012) and Nexus 7 (2013) are both 7inch tablets but with different densities. You can add hdpi or xhdpi with sw600dp like values-sw600dp-hdpi. For phones do the same swXXXdp but try not to do that and use screen-size like small, normal, large, and xlarge.
For reference see [Android official link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Changing your layouts based on density is a sign that your layouts are extremely fragile and should be reworked. DP (Density independent Pixels) ensure that each element is the right physical size, no matter what density the screen is.

Comment: Actually you both are correct. His point has more to do with the fact that you cannot control resources for both device size and screen density using only screen density qualifiers (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, etc). Take for example two devices which have the same screen density (mdpi): a small phone (sw320dp) and large tablet (sw720dp). If you attempt to create a drawable which will fit the whole screen for both, you'll end up with a tiny image (320px) scaled up to 720px or a large image scaled down. This is one case where having separate sw320dp-mdpi and sw720dp-mdpi qualifiers is appropriate.